# Issue with fork() and message queue communication in C program

Tags: c, linux, fork, ipc, message-queue

In my program, I'm attempting to fork a process when it receives the message "ON" from a message queue. Before introducing the fork, the messages work correctly:

```
    while (1)
    {
        receive_message(msg_queue_id, data, sizeof(data), getpid());
        if (strcmp(data, "ON") == 0)
        {
            puts("Received");
        }
    }
```

However, upon adding the fork, the program exhibits inconsistent behavior. The initial 10 processes seem to be affected, and it's worth noting that the fork doesn't always fail; there are instances where it succeeds.

```
    while (1)
    {
        receive_message(msg_queue_id, data, sizeof(data), getpid());
        if (strcmp(data, "ON") == 0)
        {
            pid = fork();
            CATCH_ERROR;
            if (pid == 0)
            {
                puts("Received");
            }
        }
    }
```

The error message encountered when the fork fails is as follows:

> [ERROR] src/proc.c      Line: 32        PID = 22755     Error 42 (No message of desired type)

I'm struggling to understand why forking the process intermittently causes issues with the message queue. Any insights or suggestions on potential causes and how to address them would be greatly appreciated.

My expectation was that forking the process would not interfere with the message queue operations, but the intermittent "No message of desired type" error suggests otherwise. I'm looking for insights into potential causes or alternative approaches to resolve this issue.

```
    void receive_message(int msg_id, void *msg_ptr, size_t msg_size, int msg_type)
{
    struct msqid_ds buf;
    struct msgbuf message;
    message.mtype = msg_type;

    if (msgctl(msg_id, IPC_STAT, &buf) == -1)
    {
        if (errno != ENOMSG)
            CATCH_ERROR;

        return;
    }

    if (buf.msg_qnum == 0)
        return;

    if (msgrcv(msg_id, &message, msg_size, msg_type, IPC_NOWAIT) == -1)
    {
        if (errno != ENOMSG)
            CATCH_ERROR;

        return;
    }

    memcpy(msg_ptr, message.mtext, msg_size);
}
```

Comment: Please edit question with a [mre].

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6014055/1216776

Comment: Your program doesn't distinguish the parent and child after the `fork()`. Both of them will continue the loop, trying to read from the message queue. One of them will find a message that matches its PID, the other won't.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but based on the message receiving code I posted above, the process that doesn't match the PID should simply ignore the message without raising errors.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "when the fork fails"?  I would expect to see `if(pid == -1)`, but you never check that case and instead unconditionally invoke `CATCH_ERROR`, which is probably writing an invalid error message based on whatever happens to be left in `errno`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose a process reads "ON" from the message queue. It writes "Received" and then attempts to read another message.  If `msgrcv` returns -1 and sets `errno` to ENOMSG, `receive_message` returns without writing any data to `msg_ptr` and `data` still contains "ON" from the previous read.  `strcmp` again returns 0, `fork` is called and both the parent and the child immediately invoke the `CATCH_ERROR` macro which (presumably) writes an error message based on what is currently in `errno`.  If neither `strcmp` nor `fork` have modified `errno`, then that value is still `ENOMSG`, and you see the offending error message.

Comment: I am using the process PID as the message type, so each process should be able to read only the messages sent to that specific PID. In theory, this eliminates the issue of concurrency between processes trying to read the same "ON" message. Therefore, I don't believe this is the problem.

Comment: @chiara_tummi It is exactly the problem.  The child reads its message the first time through, but it doesn't exit so it tries to read it again and performs the steps describe in this answer.  Your children need to exit.